# php verify password before change it

Tags: php

I'm confused with the new php...

I wrote below code, but something is not working.

Scenario is to Verify the password in the DB , if the password is OK then response should be OK. If not then stop the search.

```
    $currentPassword = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST['currentPassword']);
    $newPassword = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST['newPassword']);
    $ConfirmPassword = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $_POST['ConfirmPassword']);
    $oldpass = IrBuscarPassword($_SESSION['user']['username']);

        $hash = password_hash($oldpass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 13]);

        if (password_verify($currentPassword, $hash)) {
            // password valid
            $change = true;
        } else {
            $change = false;
        }
```

---

So... this is my code right now... i'm not sure if this is the good way...
Please, help me with this...

```
    if(isset($_POST['currentPassword']))
    { 

    $currentPassword = $_POST['currentPassword'];
    $newPassword = $_POST['newPassword'];
    $ConfirmPassword = $_POST['ConfirmPassword'];
    //$saltcode = IrBuscarSalt($_SESSION['user']['username']);

    $oldpass = IrBuscarPassword($_SESSION['user']['username']);
    $hash = password_hash($oldpass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 13]);

        if (password_verify($oldpass, $hash)) {
            // password valid
            //echo $oldpass;
            $change = true;
        } else { echo "bad"; }
    }
```

Comment: Fetch the user from the DB. Check the supplied "oldpass" (currentPassword) with password_verify, if it's valid then save the hash of the new password to the database. If not - show an error.

Comment: I would skip the `preg_replace` part of the code though, you probably need this on the old password as the stored hash is from a password without spaces. But there's no reason to limit the entropy of the new hashes

Comment: Changing a user's input password is a bad idea because then what they entered might not match what gets stored as their password.  What if the user is deliberately putting a space on the end of their password to throw off simple brute force attacks?

Comment: So, what can i do.... I'm confuse.. so...

Answer (score 0):

Do not hash the old password before using `password_verify` on it. Once you verify and it passed the verification, you can then hash it and proceed.